# Perl release tests vs install time tests

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I'm writing a Perl module that I want to upload to CPAN soon.  I have written a test suite for it to make sure I don't break anything between releases.  What kind of tests should be run at install time versus only at release time?  The only ones I can really nail down that are release time only are POD checkers, Perl critic checks, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, make a test a release time test if...

- it only has to do with the distribution of the module
- the results are not going to change in the user's environment
- the results don't effect the runtime
- the test is difficult to make reliable
- the test has a lot of expensive dependencies

This is a pragmatic choice and there's no hard and fast formula.  It is a balance between, on the one hand, catching all possible bugs and on the other hand the ease and reliability of installing your module.  You don't want to miss out on bugs, but you don't want false positives, and you don't want too many dependencies just to test it.

[Test::XT](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aXT) and [Test::Distribution](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aDistribution) provide a suite of stock tests to run against most modules which include such things as testing the POD, if you have certain important files like a change log, README, if your MANIFEST is correct and so on. Most of what is in them should be release only as they pass nearly all the rules above.

A good example is testing the POD, be it for correctness (Test::Pod) or completeness (Test::Pod::Coverage).  On the one hand neither effects the runtime and both require extra modules.  But the installing user might have a different POD parser which might result in broken POD.  However, the breakage is usually trivial and doesn't seriously affect the utility of the documentation.  So while testing POD at install time *might* catch some minor POD bugs, it's not worth the hassle.

Test::Perl::Critic is a clear release-only test.  The results are completely static and have no bearing on the runtime.  There would be nothing more frustrating than to have an install fail because the author used an non-canon quote style or something trivial.

[Test::Dependencies](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aDependencies) and [Test::DependentModules](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aDependentModules) are good case studies as well.  It has a lot of dependencies, it's finicky and its results are unlikely to change at install time.

Answer (score 2):

No harm in testing as much as possible at install time unless it's a test that's fragile or requires a long time to complete. Keep in mind that if you don't run a test by default, automated testers of modules on CPAN won't run them either.